# Redirect all traffic but "beta" sub-domain to Splash screen (mod_rewrite)

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, splash-screen

I'd like to redirect all my traffic to my root domain, the root domain being a Splash screen. I'd like to do this ONLY when the %{HTTP_HOST} is not beta.example.(com|es|fr).

So I've tried the following in my .htaccess file, with no luck... (infinite loop... I guess it's not getting the REQUEST_URI condition, but cannot figure out why?? I've tried almost everything)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.es$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.fr$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteRule ^.*$ / [NC,L,R=302]
```

At that point, I should have all my traffic but "beta" sub-domain redirected to the root domain. So now I'd like to Rewrite "backstage" the root domain with my Splash screen, following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.es$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^beta\.example\.fr$
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$ splash.phtml [NC,L]
```

Note: I'm using the Zend Framework, so these rules are following in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I must say, I'm stuck.

thx in advance

Comment: It'll be better, If you ask your question on SF...

Comment: Should I copy it to Server Fault? What are the differences between both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bsagols

This line from Zend is going to screw you up for sure.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

You need to put your directives above this, if not above all of the Zend stuff.  If I'm understanding you correctly, try this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"   "!^beta\.example\.(com|es|fr)$"    [NC]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css)$" [NC]
RewriteRule ".*"              "/splash.phtml"                   [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer. I've edited your code snippet though, so it doesn't rewrite to `/splash.html` when accessing an existing file / directory / symlink on the Apache HTTP server. **Key** is: `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`. See [Zend Framework rewriting rules explained (.htaccess)](http://bsagols.com/blog/2010/09/02/zend-framework-rewriting-rules-explained-htaccess/) for more details.